# How can I get rails to not render escaped quotes as \&quot;

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actionview

In my layout I have

```
<% @current_user.popups.each do |p| %>
  <% content_for :script do %>
    <%= "$(document).ready ( function() { $.jGrowl(\"#{p.message}\", { sticky: true }) });" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

And then in the script section I have

```
<%= yield :script %>
```

The problem is that this renders the escaped quotes as `\&quot;` and javascript doesn't like this.

How can I stop this from happening? Or is there another approach to this? I can't use single quotes because I'd like to have some html in the message. I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using Rails 3?  In Rails 3 html *escaping is done by default* and you must **bypass it each time** like the following: jdl had the right idea above, but it sounds like you still have issues.

```
<% content_for :script do %>
  $(document).ready ( function() { $.jGrowl("<%= raw(p.message) %>", { sticky: true }) });
<% end %>
```

But even better would be to run it through **the helper provided by rails**: `escape_javascript` so escape carriage returns and quotes

like this:

```
$(document).ready ( function() { $.jGrowl("<%= raw(escape_javascript(p.message)) %>", { sticky: true }) });
```

Comment: If jdl's answer works fine, I'd still recommend using the escape_javascript helper to escape quotes and new-lines

Comment: Thank you I needed to do this to put html in the message.

Comment: I like this answer better so I deleted mine.

Answer (score 1):

try adding .html_safe to your string in the view.

```
<%= "$(document).ready ( function() { $.jGrowl(\"#{p.message.html_safe}\", { sticky: true }) });" %>
```